# MySql table doesn't create when I try to add "AUTO_INCREMENT"

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `userinfo`.`users` 
( id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
 `username` VARCHAR NOT NULL , 
 `password` VARCHAR NOT NULL , 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Could anyone give me an insight as to why this create table function isn't working? Error code:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL ,
> `password` VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
> ENGINE ...' at line 3

new to mysql so i have no clue what the problem is. I just want a table that has the primary key increment when i add to it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `userinfo`.`users` 
( id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
 `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
 `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

You need to specify maximum character limit for VARCHAR type as above. You can set it as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks! cant believe i forgot that! works fine now.